# Particle motion and greatest distance from the origin

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

[image]

I am looking at question D. From question b, I know that the particle changes direction at sqrt(2pi). I found the integral of the velocity function from 0 to 2pi to see where the particle is as it changes its direction. I got -3.265. I wrote down the furthest distance form the origin as 3.265 to the left. However, the answer key says it is 2.265 to the left. I was wondering if anyone could help me explain this.

Thank you very much

Comment: I do not think this question deserved a negative vote. May be someone thought you were asking multiple questions in one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Particle changes direction when $\frac{t^2}{2} = \pi \implies t = \sqrt{2\pi} \, (\lt 3)$. The position of the particle at the time of changing direction -

$x = 1 - \int_0^{\sqrt {2\pi}} (1+t) \sin\frac{t^2}{2} \, dt \, \approx - 2.26548$

May be you forgot to take into account that the starting position of the particle is $x = 1$.